# How do I take a replicable random sample from a population matrix? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a huge dataset and I want to take a random sample of 5000 observations. The problem is that whenever I run the code, the results change very slightly. I want robust results that can be replicated each time the code is run. I have tried the following, but rng obviously did not affect datasample.

```
rng(100);
Y_sample = datasample(Y,5000);
```

Help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `rng` works for me (same results from `datasample` every time) on R2017b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make results reproducible within `datasample` you need to create the random number stream `RandStream`

```
s = RandStream('mlfg6331_64'); 
population = 10:20;
y = randsample(s,population,1)
```

For more details, refer to the [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html).

Comment: Thank you, done! The 1:10 part was confusing me in the official document, I didn't realize that I had to put my population in there.

Comment: @Pitlab Accepting answers that solve your problem is better than thanks. Please read ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)